# Google Cloud DataFlow job throws alert after few hours

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Running a DataFlow streaming job using 2.11.0 release. 
I get the following authentication error after few hours:

```py
File "streaming_twitter.py", line 188, in <lambda> 
File "streaming_twitter.py", line 102, in estimate 
File "streaming_twitter.py", line 84, in estimate_aiplatform 
File "streaming_twitter.py", line 42, in get_service 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 227, in build credentials=credentials) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper return wrapped(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 363, in build_from_document credentials = _auth.default_credentials() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_auth.py", line 42, in default_credentials credentials, _ = google.auth.default() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE) DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.
```

This Dataflow job performs an API request to AI Platform prediction
and seems to be Authentication token is expiring.

Code snippet:

```
def get_service():
    # If it hasn't been instantiated yet: do it now
    return discovery.build('ml', 'v1',
                           discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_SERVICE,
                           cache_discovery=True)
```

I tried adding the following lines to the service function:

```
    os.environ[
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/tmp/key.json"
```

But I get:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: File "/tmp/key.json" was not found. [while running 'generatedPtransform-930']
```

I assume because file is not in DataFlow machine.
Other option is to use `developerKey` param in build method, but doesnt seems supported by AI Platform prediction, I get error:

```
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."> [while running 'generatedPtransform-22624']
```

Looking to understand how to fix it and what is the best practice?

Any suggestions?

- Complete logs [here](https://pastebin.com/zhtMDAgV)
- Complete code [here](https://github.com/TDehaene/blogposts/blob/c8ff11fc057b6d1acd41215eb6652cb2792887e5/got_sentiment/4_streaming_pipeline/streaming_tweet.py)

Comment: I'm testing up copying credentials from GCS to local during execution and then using os.environ[
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/tmp/key.json", but would like a best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/tmp/key.json'` only works locally with the DirectRunner. Once deploying to a distributed runner like Dataflow, each worker won't be able to find the *local* file `/tmp/key.json`.

If you want each worker to use a specific service account, you can tell Beam which service account to use to identify workers.

First, [grant the `roles/dataflow.worker` role to the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) you want your workers to use. There is no need to download the service account key file :)

Then if you're letting `PipelineOptions` parse your command line arguments, you can simply use the [`service_account_email` option](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9c76dbf09f1c2dca6909708aada951d15112b5a5/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L461), and specify it like `--service_account_email your-email@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` when running your pipeline.

The service account pointed by your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is simply used to *start* the job, but each worker uses the service account specified by the `service_account_email`. If a `service_account_email` is not passed, it defaults to the email from your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` file.